# reference dictionary within array output to listbox

Tags: arrays, vb.net, dictionary, listbox

Title kind of states my problem.

I'm using an Api (For Vertical Response, an email list manager) which works fine. But for a particular method returns an Array where the information I need to reference is within a Dictionary inside that Array.

Array[list_id, list_name, list_type, member_data] <- member_data being the dictionary housing all my goodies.

Best I've managed to get is the listbox outputting "com.verticalresponse.api.NVPair[]" for each member.

**Code**

```
Protected Sub GetBounces()
    Dim listID As Integer = 284662333
    Dim isMember As Boolean = False


    Dim newSession As New loginArgs()
    newSession.username = username

    ' Your VerticalResponse username
    newSession.password = password


    newSession.session_duration_minutes = "120"

    Dim VRUser As New VRAPI()

    Try
        sessionID = VRUser.login(newSession)

        Dim GetMembers As New getListMembersArgs()

        Try

            GetMembers.session_id = sessionID
            GetMembers.list_id = listID
            GetMembers.max_records = 8

            Try
                Dim listmembers As Array = VRUser.getListMembers(GetMembers)

                lstBounces.DataSource = listmembers
                lstBounces.DataValueField = ("member_data").ToString()
                lstBounces.DataBind()

            Catch ex As Exception
                lstBounces.Text = "One: " + ex.ToString()
            End Try



        Catch listex As Exception
            lstBounces.Text = "Two: " + listex.ToString()
        End Try

    Catch ex As System.Exception
        lstBounces.Text = "Three: " + ex.ToString()
    End Try

End Sub
```

**Edit**

I have taken the suggestion of **Keith Mifsud** and added a breakpoint just before the Databind. It shows me that "listmembers" has eight indices (currently only testing by searching for 8 (total list will be close to 8000, of which about 1900 are needed.))

Each of those 8 indices contains the 4 columns I am looking at, so when I use listmembers(3) as the datasource I'm really only searching the fourth result, not the member_data column...

Is there a correct way to reference the column of results?

Something like:

```
lstbounces.DataSource = listmembers( ,3)
```

But instead of that, a correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should set the datasource as the dictionary not the array holding it

```
Try
    Dim listmembers As Array = VRUser.getListMembers(GetMembers)

    lstBounces.DataSource = listmembers(3)
    'As the datasource is a dictionary, I don't think you have to set up the display and value fields
    'lstBounces.DataValueField = ("member_data").ToString()
    lstBounces.DataBind()

 Catch ex As Exception
    lstBounces.Text = "One: " + ex.ToString()
 End Try
```

---

**UPDATE**

Based on what the collection type (dictionary within every element of an array) I would recommend you use the .net DataView with allows for expandable rows. There are some very good tutorials which can guide you to create your view

Comment: I'm not getting any exceptions (yay) but my listbox is empty whereas before it would display "com.verticalresponse.api.NVPair[]" 8x.

Comment: I see... if you put a breakpoint before the databind, do you see anything in listmembers(3)?

Comment: That does give a little more info, question edited to show result.

Comment: So I misunderstood how this collection is returned and yes you're right, using listmembers(3) would give you just the forth result. I think what you need is a dataview which allows you to have expandable rows. So each row would show you the first three columns and upon expanding, the dictionary would become visible for that row

Comment: there is a very good tutorial is you search for dataview c# winforms expandable rows on google... I know this is vb.net and I don't know if you understand c# but they are very similar and you can always use a c# to vb.net converter to understand the c# snippets

Comment: Looks like that was just what I needed, feel free to repost your comment as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks.